# Upgrade a JHipster project from v4.6.1 to 4.6.2 fails

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to upgrade a JHipster project from version 4.6.1 to version 4.6.2 but I've this error:

```
C:\Users\Andrea\workspace\Z_Test01>jhipster upgrade
Executing jhipster:upgrade
Options:
Welcome to the JHipster Upgrade Sub-Generator
This will upgrade your current application codebase to the latest JHipster version
Looking for latest generator-jhipster version...
WARNING! Something went wrong fetching the latest JHipster version number...
warning package.json: No license field
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field

events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ERROR! Exiting process
    at Environment.error (C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:140:40)
    at constructor.error (C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:1610:18)
    at shelljs.exec (C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\upgrade\index.js:141:26)
    at C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:199:9
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:262:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:921:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Were you connected to the internet?  Usually "Something went wrong fetching the latest JHipster version number..." means it couldn't get the latest version from NPM

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and then several ways. I tried this and it worked...

Open your console and go into the application’s root directory and run this:

```
jhipster upgrade --target-version=4.6.2
```

Now you just need answer some questions for resolving merge conflicts if there are any.

**UPDATE 1:** This is because cannot obtain the last version number of jhipster in npm.